# update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/gem1.8 doesn't exist

Tags: ruby

I am trying to install ruby1.8 on Ubuntu 14.04 so that I can be able to run a work application. When i run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential ruby1.8-dev ruby-dev mysql-client mysql-server git-core libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev unzip rubygems
```

I get these errors below:

> Building dependency tree    
>     Reading state information...
>   Done
>  build-essential is already the newest version.
>  git-core
>   is already the newest version.
>  ruby-dev is already the newest
>   version.
>  unzip is already the newest version.
>   libmysqlclient-dev is already the newest version.
>  mysql-client is
>   already the newest version.
>  mysql-server is already the newest
>   version.
>  ruby1.8-dev is already the newest version.
>  rubygems
>   is already the newest version.
>  libmysql-ruby1.8 is already the
>   newest version.
>  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 161
>   not upgraded.
>  1 not fully installed or removed.
>  After this
>   operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
>  Do you want
>   to continue? [Y/n] y
>  Setting up rubygems (1.8.25-1bbox3~trusty1)
>   ...
>  update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/gem1.8
>   doesn't exist
>  dpkg: error processing package rubygems
>   (--configure):
>   subprocess installed post-installation script
>   returned error exit status 2
>  Errors were encountered while
>   processing:
>   rubygems
>  E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an
>   error code (1)
>  lusekero_mwathengere@lusekero:~$

Please help....I know ruby1.8 is an old version but this is what we are using at work so I need to succeed in this installation.

Thanks, in advance, for any help rendered.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Charles. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

I ran into a similar error message while putting ruby on rails on AWS:

```
Setting up rubygems (1.8.25-1bbox3~trusty1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/gem1.8 doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package rubygems (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
rubygems
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The solution was to manually install the library for the missing alternative path. in ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems1.8
```

This allowed my install script to find the requested files.

Comment: It never occurred to me that the answer would be this simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems1.8
update-alternatives --set ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
```